# Selenium::Webdriver throwing wrong number of arguments error when used along with calabash

Tags: firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, calabash

I try to launch a **firefox** browse while running **calabash-ios** scripts... but it throws following error:

```
#<ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)>
/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.9.155/lib/calabash-cucumber/operations.rb:67:in `tap'
/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/parsers/baseparser.rb:183:in `pull'
/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/parsers/treeparser.rb:22:in `parse'
/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/document.rb:245:in `build'
/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/document.rb:43:in `initialize'
/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.35.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/extension.rb:44:in `new'
/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.35.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/extension.rb:44:in `read_id_from_install_rdf'
```

I can launch a firefox browser seperately without calabash-scripts.

How to overcome this problem?

Comment: The answer is simply that it's expecting you to pass it a parameter but you haven't. Therefore without a copy of your code, we cannot do *anything*.

Comment: 'require 'calabash-cucumber/cucumber'
require 'calabash-cucumber/core'
require 'calabash-cucumber/operations'
require 'selenium-webdriver'


def launch_browser
  Selenium::Webdriver.for :firefox
end

def quit_browser(browser)
  browser.close
end'

In steps,
following command is given:
'launch_browser'

Comment: your calabash-cucumber gem is way out of date.  the latest version is 0.9.165.  when you update, don't forget to update your [calabash.framework as well.]( https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/B1-Updating-your-Calabash-iOS-version#updating-calabash-ios)

Comment: I have updated my calabash-cucumber gem. It still did not work. I am unable to have capybara and calabash environment simultaneously